# Is there a way to search the comments as well as the questions posted?

Tags: support, comments, search

I've been trying to find a citation that someone posted, with a good resource for MathJax help.  Unfortunately, when I tried entering "MathJax", "Math Jax", or just "Jax", it returned no entries.  Is there any way to search through the comments without having to click on each question one by one?

Comment: I tend to use Google, by preceding my search terms with `site:scicomp.stackexchange.com`. For your specific case, is [this](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/tex.html#supported-latex-commands) the page you need?

Comment: Not quite... though it is a useful reference guide

Comment: Actually, I was looking for something more like href="http://www.suluclac.com/Wiki+MathJax+Syntax  with plenty of common examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to search comments at the moment.

If it's a comment that would appear as one of the first 5 comments (either by being posted first or by being upvoted), it *may* get picked up by Google's indexing and then searching for `"mathjax" site:scicomp.stackexchange.com` might work.

If you know which user posted the comment, you can also look at the Activity tab on that user's profile and filter it by comments to make the searching easier.